# Is there a way to specify that a template parameter type must be derived from a particular base class?

Tags: class, templates, parameters, radix

Is there a way to specify that a template parameter type must be derived from a particular base class?  This is how I wish it would work:

```
class  foo
{
    a_foo_function() const;
};
//.......
template  < class F : public foo >  // <<<=== my deceptively creative syntax
class bar
{
    F * pfd;
    bar(F* food){ pfd = food; }
    void f() const {  pfd->a_foo_function();  }  //guaranteed to work in my book
};
//.......
class foo                         just_a_plain_foo;
//.......
class foodish : public foo {}     a_foodish;
//.......
class foolish : public not_foo {} a_foolish;
//.......
class foodous : public foodish {} a_foodous;
//.......
typedef bar<foodish> barf;
barf a(a_foodish); //ok
barf b(a_foodous); //ok
barf c(a_foolish); //NOT ok ... foolish is not derived from foo
barf d(just_a_plain_foo); //NOT ok ... pfd pointer is to derived foodish
```

Ain't that beautiful?
But my beautiful syntax won't compile, though;  and I can't seem to find how to do this.
Note that using the base class as template parameter won't work for me, as I may have distinct and mutually incompatible classes deriving from foo.
TIA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class to take any subclass of Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109813/class-to-take-any-subclass-of-base)

Comment: Yes, static_assert would do it;  I just wasn't familiar with it.  I guess I could also use a require clause;  I'm just learning about concepts.  Thanks.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I read that question about a dozen times and I don't understand the question at all.  However, I know now the answer to my question, and that is to add a require concept is_derived.